# Sumar dentro de un innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

OK tengo un h1 dentro de ese tengo un numero al pulsar un boton lo que espero es que a ese h1 se le sumen 10 ejemplo dentro del h1 hay un 20 le doy en el boton y se suma 10 queda 30
[image: este es]

Comment: El código va como texto, además ayudaría que expongas ¿cuál es el fallo que obtienes al momento?, checa [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Antes de intentar incrementar el número debes obtener el valor del elemento en una variable, luego convertirlo en valor numérico, porque aunque sea un número `innerHTML` lo devuelve en formato texto lo que significa que "20" + "10" sería "2010" en lugar del número 30. Una vez convertido el valor de texto a número podrás sumarlo.

Obtiene el dato en formato texto

```
var num = document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML
```

Obtiene el dato convertido en número

```
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML)
```

El siguiente código, incrementa también el número

```
<h1 id="numero">20</h1>

<script>
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML);
    num += 10;
</script>
```

---

Ejemplo con botón

```js
function suma() {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("numero");
    var num = parseInt(elemento.innerHTML);
    num += 10;
    elemento.innerHTML = num
}
```

```html
<h1 id="numero">20</h1>
<button onclick="suma()">Suma</button>
```